# Counting integers that are within intervals

Tags: python, performance, interval

I am looking for a more efficient way than bruteforcing my way through in the following problem in python 3.

**Problem statement:**

**Input:**

- An array of n integers, scores, where each score is denoted by scores_j
- An array of q integers, lowerLimits, where each lowerLimits_i denotes
  the lowerLimit for score range i.
- An array of q integers, upperLimits, where each upperLimits_i denotes
  the upperLimit for score range i.

**Output:** A function that returns an array of Q integers where the value at each index i denotes the number of integers that are in the inclusive range [lowerLimits_i, upperLimits_i].

**Constraints**:

- 1 ≤ n ≤ 1e5
- 1 ≤ scores_j ≤ 1e9
- 1 ≤ q ≤ 1e5
- 1 ≤ lowerLimits_i ≤ upperLimits_i ≤ 1e9

Example: 
Given `scores= [5, 8, 7]`, `lowerLimits = [3, 7]`, and `upperLimits = [9, 7]`
I want to check how many of the integers are contained in each interval (inclusive). In this examples: intervals are `[3,9]` and `[7,7]`, and the result would be `[3, 1]`.

My code looks like this:

```
def check(scores, lowerLimits, upperLimits):
   res = []
   for l, u in zip(lowerLimits, upperLimits):
       res.append(sum([l <= y <= u for y in scores]))
   return res
if __name__ == "__main__":
   scores= [5, 8, 7]
   lowerLimits = [3, 7]
   upperLimits = [9, 7]

   print(check(scores, lowerLimits, upperLimits))
```

Comment: This has all hardcoded values. What's your actual problem statement?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Mast. I reformulated the question in a more general way.

Comment: Please take a look at the [help/on-topic]. I don't know what you're doing, why you're doing it and what the problem is, but it doesn't look like something we cover here.

Comment: You're not doing anything with N or Q, nor are you asking for them. You're only printing the values for the example provided, not for the real problem.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I looked at the formatting of other questions and tried to use a similar format.

Comment: Now we have a clear problem statement, good. Your code does not provide a solution to the problem statement. It provides a solution to the example, not the real problem. Which means your code doesn't work yet and is not ready for review.

Comment: @Mast It looks to me that the current code does solve the core of the problem (the implementation of the function). It does not implement getting the inputs when running it in some online judge but since that is also not specified in the problem statement, I think it is fine as it is now.

Comment: @Graipher There's no link to the online judge in question or I would verify it.

Comment: @Mast Indeed. Nevertheless, to me the function seems to be able to successfully solve the problem as stated, with some example usage given under the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard. I don't see any reason for the current version of the question to be on hold. Since I am currently on mobile, I am unable, though, to cast a reopen vote and the edit that made it ontopic IMO was done before the last close vote was cast, so it will not appear in the reopen queue automatically.

Comment: @Graipher You're right. I've cast the first re-open vote, so it should be in the queue now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you sort your values, you can then make an iterator on the sorted list, forward it to the lower limit, count until the first value is reached that is larger than the upper limit and discard all further values.

The sorting will add \$\mathcal{O}(n\log n)\$ time complexity, but if you have a lot of values larger than (all) your upper bounds, you could get this back.

An implementation using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) could be:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile

def graipher(scores, lower, upper):
    scores = sorted(scores)
    for l, u in zip(lower, upper):
        s = iter(scores)
        yield sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x <= u, dropwhile(lambda x: x < l, s)))
```

Since the scores are now already sorted, you could even use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html) to find the right indices to insert the upper and lower limits. The difference between the two indices will give you the number of values in range:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

def graipher2(scores, lower, upper):
    scores = sorted(scores)
    for l, u in zip(lower, upper):
        yield bisect_right(scores, u) - bisect_left(scores, l)
```

Both functions are generators. You can just call `list()` on them to consume them into a list, giving the same result as your code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   scores= [5, 8, 7]
   lowerLimits = [3, 7]
   upperLimits = [9, 7]

   print(check(scores, lowerLimits, upperLimits))
   print(list(graipher(scores, lowerLimits, upperLimits)))
   print(list(graipher2(scores, lowerLimits, upperLimits)))
```

Finally, Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?), which recommends using `lower_case` for variables and functions.

---

When running your function and my two functions on an input of the maximum defined size for `scores` and a single pair of limits, I get the following timings:

- `check`: 249 ms ± 3.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- `graipher`: 77.3 ms ± 950 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
- `graipher2`: 53.9 ms ± 772 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

When using a `scores` of length 10 and the maximum defined size for the lengths of the limits, I get:

- `check`: 2.8 s ± 112 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- `graipher`: 246 ms ± 2.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- `graipher2`: 73.1 ms ± 612 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

And finally, when using the maximum defined size for both `scores` and the limits, only `graipher2` finishes in a reasonable time (I stopped the other ones after a few minutes):

- `graipher2`: 247 ms ± 4.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

So, to summarize, sort your scores and use bisection.